# Multiple aggregates size and mean on different pandas groupby columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've referenced the similar questions byt so far can't see it:
I have a dataframe:(eval_datan)

```
    ccs5    correct aggodds
0   258     False   0.620068
1   258     True    0.461638
2   126     False   0.243570
3   48      False   0.420276
```

I did a group by to see the number of correct and false like so:

```
 eval_datan.groupby(['ccs5','correct']).size()
```

which produces:

```
ccs5  correct
1     False        28
2     False       116
      True        148
3     False       240
      True          2
4     False       400
      True          5
```

I want to add a column aggregating the aggodds column using mean as otherwise segregated above IE by ccs and correct status

Foolishly I hoped the following would work. it does not (traceback)(KeyError: 'aggodds')

```
eval_datan.groupby(['ccs5','correct']).size()['aggodds'].mean()
```

What is the most succinct way to express this?
This for instance:

```
eval_datan.groupby('ccs5').agg({'correct':'size','aggodds':['mean']})
```

does not subtotal by "correct" status

```
    correct aggodds
    size    mean
    ccs5        
1   28  0.320001
2   264 0.347982
3   242 0.357944
4   405 0.366225
5   19  0.323990
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
eval_datan.groupby(['ccs5', 'correct'], as_index=False)['aggodds'].agg({'n':'count','avg':np.mean})
```

Hope this helps.